# How fake System.Security.Principal.IIdentity using FakeItEasy?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, wif, fakeiteasy

In my app users loging in via WIF. User's credentials is stored in `System.Security.Principal.IIdentity`. Now i want to test `CreateUser()` method.
I have to in some way fake that object. I try to do something like this:
-extract method which returns that object:

```
public IIdentity GetIdentity()
{
    return Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
}
```

and then in test file do something like this:

```
    var identity = new GenericIdentity("mymail@mydomain.com");
    A.CallTo(() => _userRepository.GetIdentity()).Returns(identity);
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas how to do that in the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at WIF's ClaimsPrincipalHttpModule. It will transform a Windows identity into an IClaimsPrincipal without needing an STS.

Also have a look at [SelfSTS](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SelfSTS/) which is an extremely useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Create a fake WindowsIdentity class:

```
public class FakeWindowsIdentity : WindowsIdentity
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public FakeWindowsIdentity(string sUserPrincipalName) 
        : base(GetAnonymous())
    {
        _name = sUserPrincipalName;
    }

    public override string Name => _name;
}
```

I'm using FakeItEasy, so I create a fake `IPrincipal` like so:

```
IPrincipal fakeUser = A.Fake<IPrincipal>();
A.CallTo(() => fakeUser.Identity)
    .Returns(new FakeWindowsIdentity("domain\\username"));
```

To assign to Thread:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = fakeUser;
```